# How would an interaction with a single charge, and a charged weightless carrying particle behave?

Tags: charge, interactions, strong-force, color-charge

We learnt about, among the other three fundamental interactions, the strong interaction. The particles that are affected by it are those with color-charge. It's carrying particles, gluons, have a nonzero color-charge, thus thake part in the interaction themselves. The lecturer made a remark on that's makes the interaction so complicated, and intuititively it indeed does - but how exactly? We proceeded describing the color-symmetry (color-octet/singlet, Gell-Mann matrices, etc.) and looked at an example interaction (showing how the color-charge changes), but we never actually explained how the charged property of the carrying particle changes things. The three different charge makes it hard to come up with an intuitive picture - so I'd like to consider an analogue.

Take the electromagnetic force. It's working is well-known and intuitive, with a single kind of charge. It's carrying particle, photon, is as massless as the gluons, but it has a zero electromagnetic charge - so they don't participate in the interaction, only transmit it. Change now one property of the photon: make it have a nonzero *q* charge.

*How would this interaction, with one charge and a weightless charged carrying particle be different from the electromagnetic force, both subatomically (-> Feynmann-diagram) and macroscopically?*  (Or is there some theorem that forbids even the theoretic existence of such a force?)

As an example: would we experience something alike the color confinement? Would it still have infinite range? Would particles change charge during interactions? etc.
What I'm looking for is an intuitive picture about what does the color-charge of the gluons cause.

Comment: I want you to get an answer from people much better at this than I, but your title  question **If photons had charge, how would the electromagnetic interaction be different**  has two problems, imo.1. Its very general (i.e. what type of charge, how much charge...) 2. but more importantly, you want an answer to the result of breaking a law of nature, but in terms of other laws of nature.  Once you start down that road, you are in effect, asking for opinions on alternate universes.

Comment: **but it has a zero electromagnetic charge - so they don't participate in the interaction, only transmit it.** The photon does get involved, it transfers momentum.  **What I'm looking for is an intuitive picture about what does the color-charge of the gluons cause.** I don't think group theory allows for useful mental pictures.

Comment: @Countto10 I disagree. True, I don't know how well the propertities of the fundamental forces are theoretically estabilished, but - as we lack a real fundamental theorem - I think they're closer to being axioms based on experimental results, than being actual laws. As such, I'm not sure - but I asked it - if there's anything that rules out the theoretical possibility of an interaction analogous to an electromagnetic interaction with a charged carrying particle.

Comment: @Countto10 Regarding the group theory, I must admit I have zero knowledge on that topic. An answer describing how the group theory forbids such a force is thus - intentionally - a valid answer...

Comment: The color charges lead to confinement, as gluons also are attracted to each other. Photons do not interact . Confined electromagnetism would give a different universe, if it would work.

Comment: My actual premise here is that we can make useful predictions on any (theoretical) force based on it's carrying particle - in this case a weightless charged one. But if that's false, my question indeed is wrong.

Comment: @Countto Edited the question as per comments.

Comment: Trying to obtain analogies always lets me down, but I don't think it's just because of my admittedly limited imagination. Every analogy I have seen has led me to a wrong assumption, because I pushed it too far. I end up trying to think in classical terms about "things" and events, that are, without the math that supports them and  allows for predictions that we can test, as hard to explain as the stuff that happens in a Harry Potter book. So I gave up on analogies, or at least I now accept that spending time with the math until the end result, is more effective at understanding.